# Rails POST links with bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to include a tooltip for a `POST` link.

Making a regular `GET` link with a tooltip works fine:

```
%a{"href" => "#", "data-original-title" => "#{pluralize poem.score, 'vote'}", "data-placement" => "right", :rel => "tooltip"}
```

However, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to specify the `POST` method for the above link.

Can I attach a tooltip to a link using the Rails link builder? Is this possible? The following example doesn't work- no tooltip.

```
=link_to "^", votes_path(vote: {poem_id: poem.id}), method: :post, "data-original-title" => "Vote up. Current score: #{poem.score}", "data-placement" => "right", :rel => "tooltip"
```

If that's not possible, what's the javascript solution?

## SOLVED

I wasn't specifying the POST method in the right way. Here's a solution:

```
%a{"href" => "#{votes_url(vote: {poem_id: poem.id})}", "data-method" => "post", "data-original-title" => "#{pluralize poem.score, 'vote'}; click to vote.", "data-placement" => "right", :rel => "tooltip"}
```

Comment: a anchor element can only refer to a http GET method. If you want to POST or PUT, use a form.

Comment: To get a link to trigger a post, javasacript must be used:  in this case, `"data-method" => "post"` is rails way of labeling a post link, and then the rails.js javascript uses that to attach an onclick event to the link to override the default behavior.  If you turn off javascript, you will find that the link no longer works as a POST operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't specifying the POST method in the right way. Here's a solution:

`%a{"href" => "#{votes_url(vote: {poem_id: poem.id})}", "data-method" => "post", "data-original-title" => "#{pluralize poem.score, 'vote'}; click to vote.", "data-placement" => "right", :rel => "tooltip"}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=link_to "^", votes_path(vote: {poem_id: poem.id}), 
    :html => {:method => :post, 
     "data-original-title" => "Vote up. Current score: #{poem.score}", 
     "data-placement" => "right", :rel => "tooltip" }
```

Comment: Didn't work... it's still trying to use GET. Just updated my post with the solution.